# How to use svg images on react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, svg

I'm trying to use svg images on my native react application, I'm developing on Android.

So I followed this tutorial =>

https://medium.com/faun/add-custom-svg-icons-to-your-expo-app-279b492f6a15

I have an error Unable to read the 'fill' property of undefined while I manage to display the image, so I try to downgrade the version of react-native- svg and the image is displayed but as soon as I integrated react-navigation my application expo on crash at startup.

So I looked for a long time for the cause of this crash.

I tried to delete the react-native-svg library, the metroconfig.js file, and expo worked again, I don't know if this was the cause of the problem.

I would like to know if people have encountered these problems or if not what is the best method which works with the current version of RN to import a svg image in a react-native application?

Thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

**EDIT**

I tested react-native-svg and react-native-transformer-svg with the latest version of react native / expo / sdk expo

From the moment I create the metro.config.js file and link it with expo by updating the app.json file, my expo application crashes at startup.

I had to use react-native-svg without react-native-transformer-svg, that is to say that I have to convert an SVG file into a reactable SVG file.

If someone has a working solution to import svg files automatically, it would be of great help to me.

Comment: I wrote a detailed article on how to use SVG icons in Expo app. https://medium.com/faun/add-custom-svg-icons-to-your-expo-app-279b492f6a15

Comment: "The author deleted this Medium story."

A wonderful example of why SO wants answers posted here, not links.

Answer (score 1):

*Important Note - I develop on a real Android device, not in Expo!*

Here is some code from an issue opened on Github that actually worked for me after some modification.

[Link to Github issue](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer/issues/29)

In my `metro.config.js` file I finally have this code:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config")

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig()

  // here I extend the extensions needed for RN because I use JSX.
  // you don't need this if you use pure JS files
  const updatedSourceExts = [...sourceExts, "jsx", "js", "json", "ts", "tsx"]

  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...updatedSourceExts, "svg"],
    },
  }
})()
```

A part of my `package-json` file:

- "react-native": "0.63.2",
- "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
- "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3"

Comment: @CallMeMrHyde - I feel your struggle so check out this code. I worked for me after having the same error as you. Also, read the whole conversation on the Github issue, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install react-native-svg-transformer

npm i react-native-svg-transformer --save
```

I'm using SVG as following and it works fine

```
import LOGOSVG from "assets/svg/logo.svg"
in render

<View>
  <LOGOSVG 
    width="100%"
    height="70%"
  />
</View>
```

Comment: That is strange, for me it doesn't.

Comment: I can confirm it's not working. Mine error is: `×
InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/lightning.3d1fcf8c.svg') is not a valid name.`